# Qual é o error.code de um e-mail inválido, no caso de um cadastro de usuário no Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

Estou criando um painel de cadastro de usuários no firebase com e-mail e senha através de um aplicativo no React-Native, então, no ato do cadastro, queria verificar se o e-mail digitado é valido.
Até onde sei,

```
auth/weak-password
```

trata-se de senha pequena...
mas no caso de um e-mail inválido inserido?

Comment: Você está fazendo alguma verificação? Como está o código que você criou para isso? A proposito o método weak-password trata senhas fracas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa!
Existem algumas mensagens relacionadas a validação de usuário/e-mail, sendo as principais :

auth/invalid-email   O valor fornecido para a propriedade de usuário email é inválido. Precisa ser um endereço de e-mail de string

auth/user-not-found Não há registro de usuário existente correspondente ao identificador fornecido.

auth/email-already-exists   O e-mail fornecido já está em uso por outro usuário. Cada usuário precisa ter um e-mail exclusivo.

Uma referência completa : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors?hl=pt-br